# Angular 2 Service not returning value assigned

Tags: angular

I am using service for sending data from a component to other.

My service follows

```
import {
    Injectable
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    values = new Array();

    setValues(values): void {
        this.values = values;
    }

    getValues(): any[] {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

Setting value in a component

```
setType(type) {
  this.values["plan"] = "HMO";
  this.homeService.setValues(this.values);
}
```

Getting value in other

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.homeValues = this.homeService.getValues();   
  console.log(this.homeValues);
}
```

Above console printing [], how to get assigned values from service?

Answer (score 4):

You must use Observable

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    values:Observable<any> = [];

    setValues(values): void {
        this.values.next(value);
    }

    getValues(): Observable<any> {
        return this.values.getValue();
    }
}
```

and in your component, you use

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.homeService.values.subscribe(v => this.homeValues = v );   

}
```

Comment: I tried like this, coming SelectTypeComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: are you import HomeService and defined it in the constructor, like constructor(private homeService:HomeService )

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong with `this.values["plan"] = "HMO";`.

This line would make and object like `{plan:'HMO'}`

So when you set this value to your service it does not save an array as you would expect.

Getting this value in turn would then return an empty array.

First change you could do is to type the `setValues`

```
 setValues(values:any[]): void {
        this.values = values;
 }
```

Secondly you have to change the first line I mentioned to actually make an array.

For example:

```
this.values = ["HMO"];
```